# Why in ConcurrentHashMap locking mechanism is changed from Reentrant to Synchronized?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8

I see that the implementation of Put in new ConcurrentHashMap is based on Synchronization locking mechanism rather than Segments extending Reentrant locks. Can anyone help in understanding why this has been done? Is there a performance or scalability benefit of this?

Comment: You can use [the annotated source](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/annotate/29e522153769/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java) to find the commit that changed the relevant lines.

Comment: As per the [ annotated source ]( https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/annotate/29e522153769/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java ) it is done to save some extra space which otherwise getting used in creating seperate lock object.